# Angular PWA does not update

Tags: angular, angular6, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I've a problem with my angular 6 app using Service Workers.

It doesn't update automatically, and as I'm making new versions every week, my users get outdated frequently.

Here's my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/services/data.service';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
declare var M: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'MyApp';

  public modalUpdate:any;

  constructor(public dataService: DataService, public updates:SwUpdate) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('current version is', event.current);
      console.log('available version is', event.available);
      localStorage.setItem("version",event.current.appData["version"]);
      localStorage.setItem("versionHash",event.current.hash);
      updates.activateUpdate().then(() => this.modalUpdate.open());
    });
    updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
      localStorage.setItem("activatedVersion",event.previous.appData["version"]);
      localStorage.setItem("activatedVersionHash",event.previous.hash);
      console.log('old version was', event.previous);
      console.log('new version is', event.current);
    });
   }

   updateApp(){
    window.location.reload();
    console.log("se está actualizando");

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modalUpdate = new M.Modal(document.querySelector('#modalUpdate'));
  }

}
```

But it seems that never triggers the updateApp method. when I see NGSW debug info by accessing to /ngsw/status, I see this:

```
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver state: NORMAL ((nominal))
Latest manifest hash: none
Last update check: never



=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: never
Last update run: never
Task queue:


Debug log:
```

So It says that never has been updated or checked for updates (as I read it)

Here's my ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "MyApp",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/*.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "/assets/fonts/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "games",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/games/fk/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/**",
          "https://picsum.photos/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The #modalUpdate element is a modal with a button that triggers the updateApp function, and it never works (It seems like updates.available and updates.activated never are triggered).

It also happens that when the user opens the page from Chrome directly AND refreshes it, the page gets updated, but I need the app refreshes from itself without open the browser, and sometimes even from the browser, even when it has loaded the new version, it comes back to a previous one.

It's supposed to update automatically every time the app is loaded, so I don't know why the cache is never refreshed.

I'm almost desperate about it. What should I do, or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, when the app is updated to the latest version, it comes back after sometime to previous version

Comment: It's hard to tell, go to your production app and check this URL for any error `/ngsw/state`

Comment: @Ploppy 
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver state: NORMAL ((nominal))
Latest manifest hash: none
Last update check: never



=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: never
Last update run: never
Task queue:


Debug log:

Comment: Most likely after an update: 1. Your users load their cached version 2. The update happens in the background while they use the site for more than a couple of seconds 3. The next time they open the site they should see your updates. - Check to see if you observe that happening. I thought mine was not updating also until I observed this.

Comment: I've edited with a better wording. I've looking for a workaround for weeks but I didn't get one.

Comment: @Mathias
I show the version of the app (I modify it in a component with every build) and it is the way I can say that the app is not being updated

Comment: So you tried the steps I listed and do not see things getting updated on the second time opening the app? Important: make sure you leave the app open for a bit on the first visit. Enough for it to load the updates.

Comment: @Mathias How much is it enough time? I've let it opened for more than five minutes, and even close and reopen the app (it should update) and it does not  update.

Comment: If you look at the dev tools Network tab you should get an idea of how long it takes your app to load. You are right, it should update in that time. One more guess - have you checked in different browsers? Not sure which you are testing with. Also does this happen to others?

Comment: It works "fine" for chrome for wintows 7, but I need it working for chrome on android as a standalone app. As I said, the "page" refresh from browser, but not from app itself

Comment: Try checking this [post](https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/pwa-create-a-new-update-available-notification-using-service-workers-18be9168d717), to make your service worker check what files will be cached and inside your webapp listen to `isUpdateAvailable` then act accordingly.

Comment: Hi there. Did you find a fix for this? I am having the same issue: PWA Angular App not updating unless users manually refresh. No error is given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you has the service worker registered. There is a bug and maybe it is not registered automatically. Try this in the main.ts of your angular application:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(() => {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('./ngsw-worker.js');
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I implemented this and am still having the same issue as op